# create image rollover with sprites from asp.net image framework

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, image

I am creating sprites for my site using [Sprite and Image Optimization Framework Preview 2](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/50869) . I want to create css image rollovers with these sprites. How can I achieve this?

Heres what I have tried for the css, i copied the code generated by the framework for the hovere image and pasted like so:

```
.vote-down-gif:hover
{
width:23px;
height:11px;
background-image:url(sprite0.png);
background-position:-512px 0;
}
```

and this is in my view:

```
   <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" class="vote-down-gif " />
```

Comment: Your question says to me: "Go download this framework and tell me how to use it." Can you post what you have tried so far? :)

Comment: Documentation: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/50869#DownloadId=144353

Comment: @Kyle - I suppose it does, but wasnt intended to mean that. The framework has generated sprites for me. I have added a hover property to the image and applied the generated code for the hover image. but it just flicker to blank when i hover it.

Comment: In that case, can you post the code? We can definitely answer better with that :)

Comment: @Damien I have read the documentation and know how to use the framework - i just cant get a simple hover working. might have to go down the jquery route!